# In Visual Studio 2013 when I add an existing form then controls don't appear on designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer, form-control

I'm working on a windows form application. I start a new project. I delete the Form1 stuff from the new project. I go and add from existing in the solution explorer and choose Form1.cs, Form1.Designer.cs, and Form1.resx from another project. When I look at the designer Form1 just looks blank, like a new one would with none of the controls appearing. The program still compiles fine with all it's controls intact. Did I miss a step somewhere?  I've closed and reopened the project etc. This happens every single time repeatedly so I believe I'm missing something but searching here or the rest of the web hasn't provided me a solution. Maybe it's just assumed to be known by everyone already?

I am just learning c# and Visual Studio so hopefully I didn't miss something stupid. I was following direction for how to do this from a book. Some projects are re-used to teach a new idea so they have you start a new project and add in existing items from the original to then work on the new idea.

Comment: If you delete `Form1` - how are you adding it `from existing`? And why wouldn't it be blank if you started `a new project`?

Comment: In the solution explorer with the namespace selected I right click > Add > Existing Item - then choose the Form1 items which had already been coded and designed from another project.
If Form1 already exists, which it does in a new project, I get an error, so I deleted it before adding the existing item.

Comment: I don't think its necessary to manually add `Form1.Designer.cs` and `Form1.resx`. I think when you manually add `Form1.cs`, it's smart enough to do the rest.

Comment: Thanks Icemanind! I tried only adding Form1 from the other project and no other files. This brought it everything else and the controls were all there. I also tried not deleting Form1 and just adding the one Form1.cs from the existing project. First it asked if I wanted to replace my current one. When I had multiple files selected it just told me no that exists. After I said okay it told me it would grab the designer and resx to which I said okay and then it realized it needed to rebuild it and walla!

Comment: icemanind make that an answer and I can mark it as a solution.  
I was following directions in the c# Head First book fwiw.  
They didn't exactly say add all the items I may have over thought. They said add Form1.cs with a note that I would also need the Form1.designer.cs and Form1.resx files. I thought that meant I should also select them. I now realize they meant those will also end up coming over.

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2013 I chose "Add existing Item" and just selected the .cs files, don't add *.Designer.cs and *.resx files. Then waited for few minutes and restarted VS2013.  Designer.cs and resx files appeared as associated with Forms but they were excluded. I right clicked them and chose "Include In Project". Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are loading the `Form1` that you think you are loading.

By default, Visual Studio 2013 (on Windows 7) will create a folder in Documents (C:\Users*Your user name*\Documents) called "Projects".  Whenever you create a new project from within Visual Studio by going to File->New Project, Visual Studio will (by default) create a new folder in the Projects folder with the project name.

I think when you "delete" Form1, you're not actually deleting it, just removing it from the project.  When you go to add Form1, you're just selecting it from the same project folder, when you actually wanted to load it from a different project folder.

Try this:  In your current project (the one where you deleted Form1 and then added it), in the Solution Explorer, right click on the project, and select "Open Folder in File Explorer".
[image]

This will open the project folder on disk.  Now, delete Form1.cs from within Visual Studio, and switch back to the project folder.  If Form1.cs is still in that project folder, then you just removed it from the project.  The actual files still exist on disk.  When adding existing items, Visual Studio will typically default to the selected project folder.

I have a very strong suspicion that the Form1 that you are really looking for resides in a different project folder.  Without knowing the book or tutorial you are following, I can't give you any hints as to where the Form1 you want is located.

Comment: No, when I right click Form1.cs in the solution explorer it is actually deleted from the project and it's files are also deleted. I am correctly picking the Form1 from the other project. Remember, I can still compile and run the code just fine after I add the Form1 from another project. It's just that when I open the Form1 in designer none of the controls show up. If I do something like drag and resize the window in Form1.cs[Design] then try and Start the program again I get an error 

Type 'TestFormAdd.Form1' already defines a member called 'InitializeComponent' with the same parameter types

Comment: Ah.  That makes more sense.  Do a global search inside of Visual Studio (Ctrl-Shift-F) for "InitializeComponent()".  There should be exactly 2 results: one in Form1.cs, and one Form1.designer.cs.  If there are 2 or more results with the same file name, delete the duplicate files.  There are probably 2 Form1.designer.cs files in your project, and the compiler doesn't know how to handle the multiple `InitializeComponent` methods.

Comment: Maybe this is related to the problem. When there is a Form is VS it shows up like this.<br/>
![Original](http://i.imgur.com/P1tZeFl.jpg)
<br/>
But in the new one it isn't nested like that.<br/>
![New](http://i.imgur.com/IgOth25.jpg)

Comment: Thanks CurtisHx The IDE seems to add a second InitializeComponent() to Form1.cs This lets me compile again but the [Design] still doesn't show the controls for Form1 and the same thing happens again if I do anything like a resize add another control etc. I did not find any duplicate file names within the project folder, like in a subdirectory or anything.

Comment: Can you update your question with a screeshot of the project after adding Form1, and post the code from Form1.cs, Form1.designer.cs, and Program.cs?